# Automatically add product_categories to nav_menu

Tags: categories, menus

I've been googling around about days working for a client and would like that every time they add a product_category, it should get automatically added as a sub-menu item in the Primary navigation menu but still had no luck.

Briefly I want to have a dynamically generated menu of my all product_categories.

I've tried filtering through this code:

```
function new_nav_menu_items($items, $args) {

$args = array(
            'taxonomy'   => "product_cat",
            'hide_empty' => true,
            'hierarchical' => 1,
        );

$product_categories = get_terms($args);

         foreach($product_categories as $sub_category) {
            $items = $items . '<li class="menu-item"><a href="'. get_term_link($sub_category->slug, 'product_cat') .'">'. $sub_category->name .'</a></li>';
        } 
    
        return $items;
}

add_filter( 'wp_nav_menu_items', 'new_nav_menu_items', 10, 2);
```

But I couldn't implement hierarchically order and sub-menus.
Any ideas how should I reach this goal?

Answer (score 2):

put this on your functions.php  and then call the function in whatever page desired. this code is prepare to use css.

```php
if (! function_exists('menu_categories')) {
  function menu_categories(){
    $cat_args = array( 'orderby' => 'name', 'order' => 'asc', 'hide_empty' => true);
    $cats = get_terms( 'product_cat', $cat_args ); ?>
    <h1>Categories</h1><?php
    foreach ($cats as $key => $cat):
      if ($cat->parent == 0): ?>
        <div class="tc-menuint-1">
          <a href="<?php echo get_term_link($cat) ?>"><?php echo $cat->name; ?></a></li>
          <div class="tc-menuint-2"><?php
            foreach ($cats as $key => $cat2):
              if ($cat2->parent == $cat->term_id): ?>
                <div class="tc-menuint-3">
                  <li><a href="<?php echo get_term_link($cat2) ?>"><?php echo $cat2->name; ?></a></li>
                  <div class="tc-menuint-4"> <?php
                    foreach ($cats as $key => $cat3):
                      if ($cat3->parent == $cat2->term_id): ?>
                        <li><a href="<?php echo get_term_link($cat3) ?>"><?php echo $cat3->name; ?></a></li><?php
                      endif;
                    endforeach; ?>
                  </div>
                </div> <?php
              endif;
            endforeach; ?>
          </div>
        </div><?php
      endif;
    endforeach;
  }
}
```

Then from anywhere we can call the function.

```php
<?php menu_categories(); ?>
```

Well is that!!

To understand the php code, we are getting all the categories like so:

```php
$cat_args = array( 'orderby' => 'name', 'order' => 'asc', 'hide_empty' => true);
$cats = get_terms( 'product_cat', $cat_args );
foreach ($cats as $key => $cat):
  echo '<a href='.get_term_link($cat).'>'.$cat->name.'</a><br>';
endforeach;
```

Once all the categories and subcategories are showing: we can filter it to show only the categories (top level):

```php
$cat_args = array( 'orderby' => 'name', 'order' => 'asc', 'hide_empty' => true);
$cats = get_terms( 'product_cat', $cat_args );
foreach ($cats as $key => $cat):
  if ($cat->parent == 0):
    echo '<a href='.get_term_link($cat).'>'.$cat->name.'</a><br>';
  endif;
endforeach;
```

If we want the sub-categories we can filter them again:

```php
$cat_args = array( 'orderby' => 'name', 'order' => 'asc', 'hide_empty' => true);
$cats = get_terms( 'product_cat', $cat_args );
foreach ($cats as $key => $cat):
  if ($cat->parent == 0):
    echo '<a href='.get_term_link($cat).'>'.$cat->name.'</a><br>';

    foreach ($cats as $key => $cat2):
      if ($cat2->parent == $cat->term_id):
        echo '<a href='.get_term_link($cat2).' style="color:red;">'.$cat2->name.'</a><br>';
      endif;
    endforeach;

  endif;
endforeach;
```

then if we want a sub-sub-categorie, we can add another block of code like the one before changing in this case $cat2 to for example $cat3, and compare it to the term_id of the parent $cat2. Now if for some reason we need more sub-categories we can go on and on...

```php
$cat_args = array( 'orderby' => 'name', 'order' => 'asc', 'hide_empty' => true);
$cats = get_terms( 'product_cat', $cat_args );
foreach ($cats as $key => $cat):
  if ($cat->parent == 0):
    echo '<a href='.get_term_link($cat).'>'.$cat->name.'</a><br>';
    foreach ($cats as $key => $cat2):
      if ($cat2->parent == $cat->term_id):
        echo '<a href='.get_term_link($cat2).' style="color:red;">'.$cat2->name.'</a><br>';
        
        foreach ($cats as $key => $cat3):
          if ($cat3->parent == $cat2->term_id):
            echo '<a href='.get_term_link($cat3).' style="color:green;">'.$cat3->name.'</a><br>';
          endif;
        endforeach;

      endif;
    endforeach;
  endif;
endforeach;
```